# sklearn GridSearchCV Reporting AUC and Accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm optimizing hyperparameters based on roc, but I also want to report the accuracy the model had. I can get the roc with .best_score_ attribute. Is there a way to get the accuracy as well ?

```
   hyperparams = {'C': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.5, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
   'tol': [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6, 1e-7], 'penalty': ['l1', 'l2']}
   kfolds = StratifiedKFold(7)
   self.model_ = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), hyperparams,
                              scoring='roc_auc', 
                              cv=kfolds.split(self.all_sets_X, self.all_sets_y))
   self.model_.fit(self.all_sets_X, self.all_sets_y)
   print({'roc_auc': self.model_.best_score_})
   print({'best_params': self.model_.best_params_})
```

Comment: `.best_score_` provides the accuracy, if you set the `scoring` parameter to `accuracy`

Comment: `self.model_.best_estimator_.score(self.all_sets_X, self.all_sets_y)` will provide accuracy for the best estimator.

Comment: I hand't found that post. So there is not a straightforward solution for this. Strange